# Only allow GKE private clusters' secondary IP range to access internet through CloudNAT

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a GKE private cluster and CloudNAT for the corresponding vpc & subnet. I'd like to let my Kubernetes pods access the internet through CloudNAT service.

I found that I must set the IP range settings in CloudNAT to "All primary and secondary IP range" to make it work. When I choosed only the secondary IP ranges to which my pods will be allocated, the pods could't access the internet.

Is there any way to only allow a secondary IP range to use CloudNAT instead of the whole subnet's primary IP range?

[image]

Comment: Do you have a VPC Native cluster?

Comment: As you did, **custom subnet IP address range** is one of the procedures to create as many Cloud NAT gateways as necessary, subject to [Cloud NAT quotas and limits](https://cloud.google.com/nat/quota#limits). please make sure your IP address range meets the quotas and limits.([source](https://cloud.google.com/nat/docs/overview#specs-subnet-ranges))

Comment: Yes I have a VPC native cluster. From the settings shown in the image, it should not violate any limits?

Comment: Make sure that the subnet region which is used for secondary IP range should match with Cloud NAT region then only instances /resources are able to access the internet for that specific IP range. Here is the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/alias-ips#cluster_sizing_secondary_range_pods) for secondary IP addresses ranges for pods.  
Refer this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/alias-ips#cannot_use_--disable-default-snat_without_--enable-ip-alias) for more information on Debugging cloud NAT.